# Spring Web Flow exception handling

Tags: spring, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

How to prevent exception, 
if `requestParameters.sortBy` is passed as string (`java.lang.NumberFormatException`) or is missing (`java.lang.NullPointerException`)?

```
<view-state id="journeySearch" model="journeyForm">

     ...

    <transition on="sort">
        <set name="journeyCriteria.sortBy" value="requestParameters.sortBy" type="int" />
        <evaluate expression="bookingService.searchJourneys(journeyCriteria)" result="viewScope.journeys" /> 
    </transition>
</view-state>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`requestParameters.sortBy` will be null if it doesn't exist, but it should not throw a `NullPointerException`

about the NumberFormatException, you could use something like that:

```
<global-transitions>
    <transition on-exception="java.lang.NumberFormatException" to=""/>
</global-transitions>
```

you could also implement your own exception-handler and use it with `<exception-handler bean=""/>` you can use it at the flow or state level.

Comment: i have similar issue can you help @rptmat57  following is the link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74301528/spring-web-flow-how-to-handle-flow-exception-org-springframework-webflow-execu