# Providing a user-friendly error page for missing input

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

I have a flow that has an `input required="true"`. If for some reason a person bookmarks or shares a link to the middle of the flow, since there's no input, the flow throws an exception for the missing input, and I get a generic 500 error page. Is there a way to specify a view to be rendered in this case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring Web Flow exception handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086376/spring-web-flow-exception-handling)

Comment: @Tony That question is dealing with exceptions on views or transitions, not on the entry to the flow itself, which doesn't appear to have an explicit hook.

Comment: @chrylis Tony is correct in the sense that if you use required="true" all that will do is throw an exception (that you must catch and handle appropriately) indicating that the param was missing.. Although the syntax is concise I personally do not use required="true" for the reason just stated and manually validate the input params myself. See my answer below

Comment: @Airduster It's not *possible* to catch that exception. It's thrown from code that's higher-level than the flow itself.

Comment: @chrylis Maybe that's why I opted to use the manual solution for this problem all this time :) I've never tried this but maybe you can handle the exception if you pass the input param from a parent flow -> subflow? and maybe the parent flow can handle the exception throw from the subflow using the link/answer tony supplied. I suspect the "required" attribute in the input tag was only meant to be used with subflows (much like the output tag only works in subflows passing back values to/from parent caller flow)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the input required="true" attribute and validate the input param yourself via a decision-state.

For example:

```
<input name="id"/>

<decision-state id="createOrEdit">
      <if test="requestParameters.id != null" then="editView" else="createView"/>
</decision-state>

<view-state id="createView" view="flows/v/create" model="modelObj"> 
           <!-- contents omitted -->
</view-state>

<view-state id="editView" view="flows/v/edit" model="modelObj"> 
           <!-- contents omitted -->
</view-state>
```

So in the above example we receive a request parameter of 'id'. We validate this parameter to see if it is null or not and make a decision as to which view-state to proceed to based on this null check.

Optionally,

1. Inside the 'if' the values of "then" and "else" can reference not just view-states but any other action-state or even another decision-state.
2. you can add multiple 'if tests' within 1 decision-state.

Comment: That's the unfortunate conclusion I've been coming to, but I hoped there was a more generalized solution.

Comment: @chrylis Yea now a days I only use webflow for "simple" use cases now a days for reasons such as this.