# Spring Web Flow How to handle flow exception ( org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SnapshotNotFoundException ) and redirect?

Tags: java, spring-webflow

I have similar code inline with this [repo](https://github.com/vakho10/Java-Spring-Boot-with-Web-Flow-and-Thymeleaf), in case of normal exception I'm able to redirect to the designated page as expected using global exception as follows

```
<global-transitions>
<transition on-exception="java.lang.Exception" to=".. "/>
</global-transitions>
```

While in case of an invalid url example following is invalid url

[image]

which has thrown the following exception

```
org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SnapshotNotFoundException
```

as following

```
2022-11-03 15:14:18.930  INFO 22779 --- [nio-9090-exec-6] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Replacing scope 'request' from [org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestScope@1c23aec5] to [org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestScope@7e2b9574]
2022-11-03 15:14:27.517 ERROR 22779 --- [nio-9090-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.FlowExecutionRestorationFailureException: A problem occurred restoring the flow execution with key 'e1s12'] with root cause

org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SnapshotNotFoundException: No flow execution snapshot could be found with id '12'; perhaps the snapshot has been removed? 
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.impl.SimpleFlowExecutionSnapshotGroup.getSnapshot(SimpleFlowExecutionSnapshotGroup.java:73) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.impl.DefaultFlowExecutionRepository.getFlowExecution(DefaultFlowExecutionRepository.java:111) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:167) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:254) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

in case of invalid url like following

```
http://localhost:9090/register;jsessionid=4716C2F2C2D33D27FE69402F0037D9AC?execution=e1sD
```

it will throw another exception as following

```
2022-11-03 15:37:17.092 ERROR 22779 --- [nio-9090-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]: Servlet. service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.BadlyFormattedFlowExecutionKeyException: Badly formatted flow execution key 'e1sD', the expected format is 'e<executionId>s<snapshotId>'] with root cause

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "D"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:983) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.support.AbstractFlowExecutionRepository.parseSnapshotId(AbstractFlowExecutionRepository.java:219) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.support.AbstractFlowExecutionRepository.parseFlowExecutionKey(AbstractFlowExecutionRepository.java:120) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:163) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:254) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

How to navigate to a designated page on similar unhandled exception.
I found couple of answers but not able to successfully implement and resolve. Can anybody help?

Following is my [code](https://github.com/prparamesh/spring/) in git

Application.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

WebFlowWithMvcConfig.java

```
package com.example.demo.config;

import java.util.Collections;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Description;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.webflow.config.AbstractFlowConfiguration;
import org.springframework.webflow.definition.registry.FlowDefinitionRegistry;
import org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.ViewFactoryCreator;
import org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.support.FlowBuilderServices;
import org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutor;
import org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator;
import org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter;
import org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.webflow.view.AjaxThymeleafViewResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.webflow.view.FlowAjaxThymeleafView;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver;

@Configuration
public class WebFlowWithMvcConfig extends AbstractFlowConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFacotryBean;

    @Bean
    public FlowDefinitionRegistry flowRegistry() {
        return getFlowDefinitionRegistryBuilder() //
                .setBasePath("classpath:flows") //
                .addFlowLocationPattern("/**/*-flow.xml") //
                .setFlowBuilderServices(this.flowBuilderServices()) //
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public FlowExecutor flowExecutor() {
        return getFlowExecutorBuilder(this.flowRegistry()) //
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public FlowBuilderServices flowBuilderServices() {
        return getFlowBuilderServicesBuilder() //
                .setViewFactoryCreator(this.mvcViewFactoryCreator()) // Important!
                .setValidator(this.localValidatorFacotryBean).build();
    }
    // ----------------------------------------------------------

    @Bean
    public FlowHandlerMapping flowHandlerMapping() {
        FlowHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new FlowHandlerMapping();
        handlerMapping.setOrder(-1);
        handlerMapping.setFlowRegistry(this.flowRegistry());
        return handlerMapping;
    }

    @Bean
    public FlowHandlerAdapter flowHandlerAdapter() {
        FlowHandlerAdapter handlerAdapter = new FlowHandlerAdapter();
        handlerAdapter.setFlowExecutor(this.flowExecutor());
        handlerAdapter.setSaveOutputToFlashScopeOnRedirect(true);
        return handlerAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewFactoryCreator mvcViewFactoryCreator() {
        MvcViewFactoryCreator factoryCreator = new MvcViewFactoryCreator();
        factoryCreator.setViewResolvers(Collections.singletonList(this.thymeleafViewResolver()));
        factoryCreator.setUseSpringBeanBinding(true);
        return factoryCreator;
    }

    @Bean
    @Description("Thymeleaf AJAX view resolver for Spring WebFlow")
    public AjaxThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {
        AjaxThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new AjaxThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(FlowAjaxThymeleafView.class);
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(this.templateEngine());
        viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    @Description("Thymeleaf template resolver serving HTML 5")
    public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    @Description("Thymeleaf template engine with Spring integration")
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(this.templateResolver());
        return templateEngine;
    }
}
```

HomeController.java

```
package com.example.demo.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/")
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello, world!");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

RegisterHandler.java

```
package com.example.demo.handlers;

import org.springframework.binding.message.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.binding.message.MessageContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.example.demo.models.BillingInfo;
import com.example.demo.models.PersonalInfo;
import com.example.demo.models.RegisterModel;

@Component
public class RegisterHandler {

    public RegisterModel init() {
        return new RegisterModel();
    }

    public void addPersonalInfo(RegisterModel registerModel, PersonalInfo personalInfo) {
        registerModel.setPersonalInfo(personalInfo);
    }

    public void addBillingInfo(RegisterModel registerModel, BillingInfo billingInfo) {
        registerModel.setBillingInfo(billingInfo);
    }

    public String saveAll(RegisterModel registerModel, MessageContext error) {
        String transitionValue = "success";

        // XXX Save model in database or somewhere else...
        error.addMessage(new MessageBuilder(). //
                error() //
                .source("registration") //
                .defaultText( //
                        String.format("Couldn't register user with username: %s!",
                                registerModel.getPersonalInfo().getUsername())) //
                .build());
        transitionValue = "failure";

        return transitionValue;
    }

    public String validatePersonalInfo(PersonalInfo personalInfo, MessageContext error) {
        String transitionValue = "success";

        // Checking that username is not equal to 'Vakho' :d XXX do whatever you want!
        if (personalInfo.getUsername().equalsIgnoreCase("Vakho")) {
            error.addMessage(new MessageBuilder(). //
                    error() //
                    .source("username") //
                    .defaultText("You are not allowed to use Vakho as the username!") //
                    .build());

            transitionValue = "failure";
        }

        // Checking if password matched the confirm password
        if (!personalInfo.getPassword().equals(personalInfo.getConfirmPassword())) {
            error.addMessage(new MessageBuilder(). //
                    error() //
                    .source("confirmPassword") //
                    .defaultText("Password doesn't match up the confirm password!") //
                    .build());

            transitionValue = "failure";
        }
        return transitionValue;
    }
}
```

BillingInfo.java

```
package com.example.demo.models;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

public class BillingInfo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @NotBlank
    private String address;

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

PersonalInfo.java

```
package com.example.demo.models;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

public class PersonalInfo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private byte[] imageContent;

    @NotBlank
    private String username;

    @NotBlank
    private String password;

    @NotBlank
    private String confirmPassword;

    @NotBlank
    private String firstname;

    @NotBlank
    private String lastname;

    public byte[] getImageContent() {
        return imageContent;
    }

    public String getImageBase64() {
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(imageContent);
    }

    public void setImage(MultipartFile image) throws IOException {
        this.imageContent = image.getBytes();
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getConfirmPassword() {
        return confirmPassword;
    }

    public void setConfirmPassword(String confirmPassword) {
        this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
}
```

RegisterModel.java

```
package com.example.demo.models;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class RegisterModel implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private PersonalInfo personalInfo;
    private BillingInfo billingInfo;

    public PersonalInfo getPersonalInfo() {
        return personalInfo;
    }

    public void setPersonalInfo(PersonalInfo personalInfo) {
        this.personalInfo = personalInfo;
    }

    public BillingInfo getBillingInfo() {
        return billingInfo;
    }

    public void setBillingInfo(BillingInfo billingInfo) {
        this.billingInfo = billingInfo;
    }
}
```

signup-flow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow.xsd">

    <var name="personalInfo" class="com.example.demo.models.PersonalInfo" />
    <var name="billingInfo" class="com.example.demo.models.BillingInfo" />
    
    <!-- returning and adding inside flow registerModel instance -->
    <on-start>
        <evaluate expression="registerHandler.init()"
            result="flowScope.registerModel" />
            
            
    </on-start>

    <!-- is the start state -->
    <view-state id="personal" view="flows/register/signup-personal" model="personalInfo">
        <transition on="billing" to="validatePersonal" />
        <on-exit>
            <evaluate expression="registerHandler.addPersonalInfo(flowScope.registerModel, personalInfo)"></evaluate>
        </on-exit>
    </view-state>
    <action-state id="validatePersonal">
        <evaluate expression="registerHandler.validatePersonalInfo(personalInfo, messageContext)" />
        <transition on="success" to="billing" />
        <transition on="failure" to="personal" />
    </action-state>

    <view-state id="billing" view="flows/register/signup-billing" model="billingInfo">
        <transition on="personal" to="personal" />
        <transition on="confirm" to="confirm" />
        <on-exit>
            <evaluate expression="registerHandler.addBillingInfo(flowScope.registerModel, billingInfo)"></evaluate>
        </on-exit>
    </view-state>
    <view-state id="confirm" view="flows/register/signup-confirm" model="flowScope.registerModel">
        <transition on="personal" to="personal" />
        <transition on="billing" to="billing" />
        <transition on="submit" to="submit" />
    </view-state>

    <action-state id="submit">
        <evaluate expression="registerHandler.saveAll(flowScope.registerModel, messageContext)" />
        <transition on="success" to="success" />
        <transition on="failure" to="confirm" />
    </action-state>
    <!-- end state -->
    <end-state id="success" view="flows/register/signup-success" />
    <end-state id="home" view="externalRedirect:contextRelative:/" />
    <!-- Global Transition -->
    <global-transitions>
         <transition on="home" to="home" validate="false" /> 
    </global-transitions>
</flow>
```

And this is the project structure

[image]

I came across the answer of dbreaux but I'm not able to implement the same

Comment: @rptmat57 can you please guide how to use exception handler ?

Comment: Not sure this is a separate question from https://stackoverflow.com/q/74071028/796761. And it doesn't look like you've tried creating a custom FlowHandlerAdapter and adding a handleException() method to it?

Comment: its in git i have in the following url https://github.com/prparamesh/spring/

Comment: And? Can you tell if it's loaded? If it's being called? If it's trying to redirect? Also, note the version you currently have only looks for the SnapshotNotFound, not the one where you use an improperly formatted execution key. Also, looking at your source, name the bean "register" to match the name of the flow.